# Rows and columns maze recursion error

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow, backtracking, maze

I was given code that contained everything needed to build a maze. My job is to write the `makeMove` method used to solve the maze.
This is what I have so far:

```
protected void makeMove( int row, int col )
{
    int MAX_ROWS = maze.length;
    int MAX_COLS = maze.length;
    boolean found = false;
    boolean[][]visited = new boolean[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS];
    //visited[startRow][startCol] = true;
    if (row < 0 || row >= MAX_ROWS  || col < 0 || col >= MAX_COLS  || visited[row][col] || maze[row][col] == 1)
        return;

    visited[row][col] = true;
    found = row == endRow && col == endCol;

    /*if(row == endRow && col == endCol) {
        found = true;
    }*/
    if(!found && maze[row][col - 1]!=1 && !visited[row][col]) { // move left
        makeMove(row, col -1);
        visited[row][col -1] = true;
    }
    if(!found && maze[row - 1][col]!=1 && !visited[row-1][col]) { // move up
        makeMove(row-1, col);
        visited[row-1][col] = true;
    }
    if(!found && maze[row][col + 1]!=1 && !visited[row][col + 1]) { // move right
        makeMove(row, col + 1);
        visited[row][col + 1] = true;
    }
    if(!found && maze[row + 1][col]!=1 && !visited[row + 1][col]) { // move down
        makeMove(row + 1, col);
        visited[row + 1][col] = true;
    }
```

When ran like this on a maze with 8 rows and 8 columns, I keep getting a stack overflow error.

I believe the error is showing that it is at line 42 and line 50, which would be
`42. MakeMove(row-1, col); //to move up`
and `50.makeMove(row + 1, col); //to move down`.

Have I made a logical error in these two?

Answer (score 1):

You should carry the current state of the maze as an argument of makeMove method. The state of the maze in your case is the visited matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the error you're getting, your code results in "infinite recursion" of the algorithm calling itself over and over again without properly terminating before it runs out of space in the call stack. Note that this doesn't mean that the line indicated by the stack trace is the actual cause of the error - it's where the program runs out of space, but the actual faulty logic is usually somewhere else.

One thing that's definitely causing trouble is this:

```
boolean[][]visited = new boolean[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS];
```

This creates a new 2D array of booleans (or to be precise, array of array of booleans) for each step of the recursion and initializes it to `false` (as that's the default value for booleans in Java). As a result, your algorithm will continue visiting tiles it has already visited because each recursion step gets its own array, full of `false` signifying that each tile is still unvisited. This particular problem can be fixed by passing the array as an argument with each recursion call, or storing it outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean[][]visited = new boolean[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS];
```

generating the above state for each recursion call does not store the state value. Its better to keep it as a global variable or pass as an argument.